# Deprecated animation missing expression

Tags: animation, core-animation, deprecated

I know there is a similar question to this but I am not seeing what I am doing wrong when I compare my code to the other similar questions so can someone please help me understand what I am missing? I am getting an error from Xcode saying that there is an expected expression (for animations:{)

```
if (animated) {
    
    [UIView animationWithDuration:0.30 animations:{
    self.alpha = 1.0f;
    if (animationType == MBProgressHUDAnimationZoomIn || animationType == MBProgressHUDAnimationZoomOut) {
        self.transform = rotationTransform;
    }
    
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method is `animateWithDuration`, not `animationWithDuration` .

Your animations block is missing the caret: `^{`

```
if (animated) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.30 animations:^{
        self.alpha = 1.0f;
        if (animationType == MBProgressHUDAnimationZoomIn || animationType == MBProgressHUDAnimationZoomOut) {
            self.transform = rotationTransform;
        }
    }];
}
```